# Sorting a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

The order of rows in my DataGrid does not change as it should when I click on a column header. I've implemented a custom sorter and this is the prototype of my Compare-Function, which is successfully being called:

```
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        var rowView1 = x as DataRowView;
        var rowView2 = y as DataRowView;
        var row1 = rowView1.Row;
        var row2 = rowView2.Row;
        var row1Id = Convert.ToInt32(row1[0]);
        var row2Id = Convert.ToInt32(row2[0]);

        if (SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            return row1Id.CompareTo(row2Id);
        }
        else
        {
            return row2Id.CompareTo(row1Id);
        }
    }
```

The compare function above seems to work as suggested, it simply compares Ids and in debug mode, I see that the comparisons lead to valid returns ( +1 or -1). Hower, the order of elements in the datagrid does not change. What am I missing out here? I've googled for so long that I'm close to needing glasses.. thanks for any help!

EDIT: the xaml for my grid

```
<DataGrid result:CustomSortBehaviour.AllowCustomSort="True" 
          Name="ResultDataGrid"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ResultDataTable}">
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: The order of rows does not change at all.. I'm missing something basic. I've attached the XAML for the DataGrid. It is bound to a DataTable (maybe I should bind it to an observable collection instead?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you actually need to set is [CanUserSortColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canusersortcolumns%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

So set that to true and then if that doesn't work do this.

```
<DataGrid Sorting="OnDataGridSort"
          CanUserSortColumns="True" 
          Name="ResultDataGrid"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ResultDataTable}">
</DataGrid>
```

And then all you need to give the ListcollectionView an instance of your comparer.

```
void OnDataGridSort(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
    ListCollectionView lcv = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dg.ItemsSource);
    lcv.CustomSort = [Your IComparer instance here];
    e.Handled;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the DataGrid.AllowSorting Property?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code

> allowsorting="true"

You can Use This.

```
<DataGrid  allowsorting="true" result:CustomSortBehaviour.AllowCustomSort="True" Name="ResultDataGrid" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ResultDataTable}">
    </DataGrid>
```